# SQL Server : showing Empty Row Select TOP 5

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm trying to show `TOP 5` brands that sold the most. I currently only have 4 Brands, as a result the output table only shows 4 rows of brands and its details. I want the output table to show a 5th row which is empty in this case. How do I modify my code to achieve what I want ?

This is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) DESC) AS No, 
    Brand.BrandName,
    ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) AS NoSold
FROM
    Brand 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Product ON Brand.BrandId = Product.BrandId
GROUP BY      
    Brand.BrandName
ORDER BY      
    NoSold desc
```

Comment: `TOP N` is not valid in MySQL, nor is the `OVER ()`. Are you actually using MS SQL Server? If you try to do this in MySQL, it will be a syntax error.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for correcting me. Yeah Im using MS SQL. Ill change that.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What do you mean by an empty row? all columns null? Why do you need this? Seems like something that should be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well it's 2012 version of MS SQL. Well,it's something small actually. I'm trying to bind the data to a gridview in ASP.Net and since I have a view gridviews next to each other and all of them have 5 rows, I just want this to have 5 rows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tally tabel and do a LEFT join to your real query .

```
SELECT
    no.Number as no,
    v.BrandName,
    COALESCE(v.NoSold,0) NoSold
FROM

    master..spt_values no
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT    TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) DESC) AS No, 
                  Brand.BrandName,
                ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) AS NoSold
        FROM          Brand LEFT OUTER JOIN
              Product ON Brand.BrandId = Product.BrandId
        GROUP BY      Brand.BrandName
        ORDER BY      NoSold desc
    ) v
    ON no.Number = v.No
WHERE
    no.Type = 'P'
    AND no.Number between 1 and 5
```

[Demo with simplified inner query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a6df/1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could manufacture some random rows, unioned with your real data, and then truncate the set with an outer `TOP` limit. A bogus ordering can also be added to ensure that your real data supercedes the manufactured data.

```
SELECT TOP 5 No, BrandName, NoSold
FROM
(
    -- Your real query
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) DESC) AS No,  
      Brand.BrandName,
      ISNULL(SUM(Product.NoSold), 0) AS NoSold,
      1 AS OrderBy
    FROM          
      Brand LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Product ON Brand.BrandId = Product.BrandId
    GROUP BY 
      Brand.BrandName

    UNION ALL

    -- Manufactured data.
    SELECT NULL AS No, NULL AS BrandName, NULL AS NoSold, 0 AS OrderBy
    FROM sys.objects
) X
ORDER BY OrderBy DESC, NoSold DESC;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82c60/1)

However this seems to me to be a better job for a presentation tier - e.g. if there really were 5 hard coded slots on your screen, you would likely want to window dress the missing data, e.g. "New brand coming soon" etc.

Comment: `FROM sys.objects` Is this intentional, or test code?

Comment: Pick any guaranteed to exist table with at least 5 rows. We aren't selecting from it. Or use a numbers pattern.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create a table in memory?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 * from (select * from (values(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) as Category(nil)) a
left join Brand on 1=1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Product ON Brand.BrandId = Product.BrandId
GROUP BY      Brand.BrandName
ORDER BY      NoSold desc
```